# how to validate the text fields related to each other in a form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form that has many text fields. Among them I have an issue with textfields (seating area and price). They can me added more and more according to the user clicks.

**Here are my conditions:**

**1 -** if (either of them) seating area textfield is empty or the price textfield is
         empty the form should not be submitted.

**2 -** I have already used jquery plugin to validate some text fields but not all.

**3 -** As the field(seating area and price are related to each other in my condition
I have used their name as array to post all the value in array like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldSeatingarea[]" id="fldSeatingarea[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldPrice[]" id="fldPrice[]">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldSeatingarea[]" id="fldSeatingarea[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldPrice[]" id="fldPrice[]">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldSeatingarea[]" id="fldSeatingarea[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="fldPrice[]" id="fldPrice[]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**4 -** and whenever the user clicks add more the table row is inserted with fields

**5 -** I have not validate these fields(`fldSeatingarea[]` and `fldPrice[]`)

**6 -** User must put value to both field of same row or to none of same tbl row.

SO my question is: how am I gonna find either of the two fields (`fldSeatingarea[]` and `fldPrice[]`) of the same table row are not empty when the form is submitted?

If either of the fields of same table row is empty the form should not be submitted.

I am doing this small experiment using html, php, and a little bit of javascript.

Comment: thaks for correcting my question .And do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fldSeatingarea[]" id="fldSeatingarea_1">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fldPrice[]" id="fldPrice_2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fldSeatingarea[]" id="fldSeatingarea_2">
</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="fldPrice" id="fldPrice_2">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Use Id's Like this to reference the fields for validation.. otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly agree with how you have used IDs on your form. I would keep a JS array variable to indicate the selected seating areas, while you populate the form.

Then you can change the ID of the element to be `fldSeatingarea_3` or `fldSeatingarea_5` and target both area and price elements by looping through the array `for (var n in selection) { //check the 'fldSeatingarea_'+n field }`

Answer (score 0):

if you wana concept than you can do it with parent and child concept through jquery

what you have to do find all tr in table and than for each tr find their fldSeatingarea[] and fldPrice[]

after it validate it if you find both are empty return false for submit event

here are some link which may help you more for it 
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ 
http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

**Just my opinion**

After submiting the form all the field(fldSeatingarea[] and fldPrice[])
is passed in an array.both of them..

You can used count to compare the how many value are inserted and how many fields are added and if they ddon`t have the same value the form will triger and not submit unless they have the same value.